# Laravel project on a single domain with multiple sub-domain on the same laravel project

Tags: laravel, dns, subdomain

I have a laravel website that has domain name eg:- www.website.com

but on the other hand I am trying it to make accessible to two more domain names

eg:- aaa.website.com   and  bbb.website.com

and also I want to be able to fetch the subdomain names from where these has been 
accessed.

thank you.

Comment: Why did you tag this both Laravel 4 and Laravel 5? Pick one.

Comment: 4 is helpful but i am trying to implement on 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `www`, `aaa`, and `bbb` to all have the same routes/content, you don't really have to do anything in Laravel. You'd just need to setup your Apache/nginx config's virtual hosts to serve the same code to all three.

For different routing per-subdomain, you can use [Laravel's subdomain routing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#sub-domain-routing).

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{sub}.example.com'], function() {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function($sub, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

If you just want to fetch the subdomain name without dealing with a routing group, `Request::getHost()` will give you the hostname, which you can parse as desired.